# Can't verify Ubuntu ISO gpg

Tags: iso, gnupg

I download Ubuntu ISO from https://ubuntu.com/download/desktop/thank-you?country=TH&version=18.04.3&architecture=amd64 and follow the instruction on how to verify the ISO from https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu#3.

I had trouble when I tried to verify the GPG part as shown

```
PS C:\Users\Aspire\Downloads> gpg --keyid-format long --verify SHA256SUMS.gpg SHA256SUMS.txt
gpg: Signature made 08/08/19 19:19:19 SE Asia Standard Time
gpg:                using DSA key 46181433FBB75451
gpg: Can't check signature: No public key
gpg: Signature made 08/08/19 19:19:19 SE Asia Standard Time
gpg:                using RSA key D94AA3F0EFE21092
gpg: Can't check signature: No public key
PS C:\Users\Aspire\Downloads> gpg --keyid-format long --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 0x46181433FBB75451 0xD94AA3F0EFE21092
>>
gpg: keyserver receive failed: Unknown error
```

so I skipped the GPG verification part and processed to check `sha256sum` instead and the result was good as shown

```
PS C:\Users\Aspire\Downloads> sha256sum -c SHA256SUMS 2>&1 | grep OK
+ sha256sum -c SHA256SUMS 2>&1 | grep OK
```

I also checked the `md5sum` and it was matched.

I want to burn a USB ISO and try Ubuntu and maybe install it dual boot with Windows 10 if I like it. Does this mean I can start burning the USB or should I wait and try to check the GPG? If so, how?

I use Windows 10 to download and verify Ubuntu by the way.

This might worth mention, but I don't know that it would help. Last night I tried to solve my gpg verification and tried to use torrent download. The file I use above is not from torrent because I couldn't open the torrent one. I don't remember much because it was very late at night and I found that all ports are closed by my university campus's network. Believe me I check. So, if there is a part of verifying gpg that needs access to a port, then, this might be what cause the problem.

Comment: Did you request the keys according to the instructions at the web page that you link to? `gpg --keyid-format long --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 0x46181433FBB75451 0xD94AA3F0EFE21092`; After that you can try to verify the file again.

Comment: I did. And that is the step that I have trouble with. The process was very long and end up with fail error.

Answer (score 0):

It works for me, I get those two keys (into a test operating system, which was not used for this purpose before). My language is Swedish, but I think it is obvious that two keys were imported.

```
tester@tester-SATELLITE-PRO-C850-19W:~$ gpg --keyid-format long --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 0x46181433FBB75451 0xD94AA3F0EFE21092
gpg: keybox '/home/tester/.gnupg/pubring.kbx' created
gpg: key D94AA3F0EFE21092: 2 duplicate signatures removed
gpg: key D94AA3F0EFE21092: 59 signatures not checked due to missing keys
gpg: /home/tester/.gnupg/trustdb.gpg: tillitsdatabas skapad
gpg: nyckel D94AA3F0EFE21092: publika nyckeln "Ubuntu CD Image Automatic Signing Key (2012) <cdimage@ubuntu.com>" importerades
gpg: key 46181433FBB75451: 2 duplicate signatures removed
gpg: key 46181433FBB75451: 106 signatures not checked due to missing keys
gpg: nyckel 46181433FBB75451: publika nyckeln "Ubuntu CD Image Automatic Signing Key <cdimage@ubuntu.com>" importerades
gpg: hittade inga nycklar med förbehållslöst förtroende
gpg: Totalt antal behandlade enheter: 2
gpg:               importerade: 2
tester@tester-SATELLITE-PRO-C850-19W:~$
```

If you tell me which iso file you have, I can check it and verify that the checksum is correct. I know that it is not a perfect way to verify that the checksum and the iso file are correct, but since you cannot get the keys, it is better than nothing.